# add a contact in two different gmail accounts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have this script to register contact(s) on Google Contacts.
It registers the contact well in a Gmail account, however I need to save the same contact in two (or more) email accounts and I don't know how to do this.

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it.

```
    function cadastrar() {
  var NOMEABA        = "Cadastro";
  var NOME           = 1;
  var SOBRENOME      = 2;
  var EMAIL          = 3;
  var FONE           = 5;

  var tabelaClientes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(NOMEABA);
  var app            = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var valores        = tabelaClientes.getDataRange().getValues();
  var linhaINICIAL   = 2;
  
  for (var linha = linhaINICIAL-1; linha < valores.length; linha++) {
    var nomeCompleto = valores[linha][NOME] + " " + valores[linha][SOBRENOME];

    if (
      valores[linha][NOME] != "" &&
      !ContactsApp.getContactsByName(nomeCompleto)[0] &&
      !ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(valores[linha][EMAIL])[0] &&
      !ContactsApp.getContactsByPhone(valores[linha][FONE])[0]
    ) {

      var contatoAtual = ContactsApp.createContact(
        valores[linha][NOME],
        valores[linha][SOBRENOME],
        valores[linha][EMAIL]
      );

      if (valores[linha][FONE]) {

        contatoAtual.addPhone(
          ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE,
          valores[linha][FONE]
        );

        var mainGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
        contatoAtual.addToGroup(mainGroup);

        app.alert("Contato " + valores[linha][NOME] + " cadastrado com telefone");
      }
    }else if (valores[linha][NOME] != "") {
        app.alert("Contato " + valores[linha][NOME] + " já cadastrado");
    }
  }

  tabelaClientes.getRange('A2:F').clearContent();
  
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1158cnzEZerlhDkU-T9yDzrF-nZeX4AkHMI-jdtXaCJ0/edit#gid=845347411

Tnks

Comment: What would be those accounts? Yahoo? Hotmail?

Comment: These are all Gmail accounts.
Gmail accounts only

Comment: Can you refer to section ---- Updating contact groups. https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3#protocol_15